# Vimwiki: <leader>ww with a remapped leader errors with E486: Pattern not found: \<:nnoremap\>

Tags: vim, neovim, remap

In case it's relevant, I'm using NVIM v0.4.3 Build type: Release.

I have remapped leader to `<SPACE>` in my vimrc like so:

```
nnoremap <SPACE> <Nop> " remove any existing mapping
let mapleader=" "
```

In vimwiki, the default of `<LEADER>ww` should open the vimwiki index. After sourcing my vimrc and typing `<SPACE>ww` I get `E486: Pattern not found: \<:nnoremap\>`. Typing `\ww` takes me to vimwiki index as if I hadn't remapped leader to `<SPACE>`. All my other leader keys work `<SPACE>qf` does quickfix, `<SPACE>rn` renames, etc.

I've only been using vim a little over a year, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Maybe localleader is involved here? But vimwiki's README clearly states it's using leader, not localleader, https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki#introduction

> To do a quick start, press ww (default is \ww) to go to your index wiki file.

Answer (score 0):

It started working and I'm not sure why. nvim froze so I killed the terminal window, and when I reopened it I tried `<SPACE>ww` and it took me to vimwiki index. I'm not sure if restarting nvim was necessary for some reason, or if I did something else between posting my question and restarting nvim. I don't think I did anything so I'm inclined to think restarting nvim solved it.